# Firefox insist on showing server IP instead of domain name

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, dns, ip

I ran out of ideas, and 2 days of googling didn't bring any new ones to try either. I got a domain name (i.e. "cool-domain.com")

At first instead changing DNS records I just did IP redirect to my server.
Opened my website, saw address name change to my server's IP in the address bar and realized that was dump.
Went back to my service provider for domain (123-reg), cancelled forwarding and antlered DNS A entries.

Left it for couple hours for DNS records to spread around.
Came back and, everything works, everywhere, any machine, any browser, if I enter "www.cool-domain.com" or just simply "cool-domain.com", either opens my website, and address bar show domain name..

Everywhere except on my laptop, but only specifically Firefox and only specifically "cool-domain.com". If I enter address with "www." - it stays, but if without "www." after opening website it shows server's IP address instead of domain name.
I cleared firefox browsing history, I flushed Firefox DNS cache, by going to "about:config" and changing both "network.dnsCacheExpiration“ and “network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod” to 0, closing re-opening and changing both back to 60.
I flushed ubuntu (my OS) DNS cache. with

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

did all those things multiple times in many different combinations to no effect.
It's seem to be very minor thing, localized to one specific browser on one specific laptop, but after two days it's beginning to slowly drive me insane. I would really appreciate if anyone would point me to right direction, of what am I missing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok nvm, after posting it, couple hours later start I thinking maybe there is something else I forgot to clear.
And yes, I did forgot cookies and site data.

Firefox "Preferences">"Privacy & Security">"Cookies and Site Data">"Clear Data.."
Marked both "Cookies and Site Data" & "Cached Web Content" and clicked "Clear"
And now everything as it should be.

I thought it's good practice to post answer, even though it's pretty dumb issue and however unlikely for anyone in some distant future to be struggling with same thing.